# Anyone has experienced to do Parallel execution of Protractor and appiium?

Tags: protractor, appium

I have one requirement to run Protractor code and InBetween need to run Appium and hold protractor and Run appium

Comment: please add more details like what you already have done. Some example code etc.

Comment: I have prepared 2 conf.js file. 1 has chrome driver capability and another one has appium driver. Now I want to run both simultaneously, any idea How to run?